# Closing the loop...featured image variable based on post id

Tags: loop, images, post-thumbnails

I am new to Wordpress templating and php development. I am working on a template to pull in multiple post thumbnails on a single page from multiple posts. The trouble I am having is that the featured images are all the same, inheriting the first post's image.  Below is my code - any help on what I need to do to have each posts contain their own featured image would be greatly appreciated :)

```
 <div class="col-lg-2 text-center">
              <div class="soap-container tire-clean">
                 <?php
                $post_id = 35;
                $queried_post = get_post($post_id);
                $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'full'); 
                ?>
              <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tireModal"><img width="100%" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail('35', 'full'); ?>"></a>
              <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tireModal"><h3><?php echo $queried_post->post_title; ?></h3></a>
              </div> 
            </div>


            <div class="col-lg-2 text-center">
              <div class="soap-container tire-clean">
                 <?php
                $post_id = 37;
                $queried_post = get_post($post_id);
                $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'full'); 
                ?>
              <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tireModal"><img width="100%" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail('37', 'full'); ?>"></a>
              <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tireModal"><h3><?php echo $queried_post->post_title; ?></h3></a>
              </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 text-center">
              <div class="soap-container mega-foam">
                 <?php
                $post_id = 39;
                $queried_post = get_post($post_id);
                $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'full'); 
                ?>
              <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#foamModal"><img width="100%" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail('39', 'full'); ?>"></a>
              <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#foamModal"><h3><?php echo $queried_post->post_title; ?></h3></a>
              </div> 
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using:

```
        $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($queried_post->ID, 'full');
```